# 9-patch looks different on real device than in XML preview

Tags: android, xml, nine-patch

I've created a 9-patch background for EditText.

XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/searchnew"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Search recorded files..."
    android:textColor="#646464" >

</EditText>
```

XML Preview:

[image]

Real device:

[image]

9-patch image:

[image]

To be honest it isn't even bothering me that much, but I'm still wondering why the hell is it happening? Why is the EditText background wider and higher on real device?

Bonus unrelated question: any idea how could I get rid of the "ugly" corners? You can see pixels individually if you look closely, but I want a pixel perfect design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the reason after doing some more research. The text inside the EditText has some default padding. That's why the 9-patch was stretched more when I ran it on real device. All I had to do was to set padding to 0.

Setting top padding to 0 example:

```
android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

Do it like this for top, bottom, left, right and background will stay fixed :)

Comment: Matthew, I realize you found the problem, but your nine patch looks odd to me. Shouldn't the dots be on the upper part of the image and the bottom? And on the left side and on the right as well?

Comment: No, as far as I know. The upper and the left dot define the scalable area. The bottom and the right dot define the fill area and are optional. Let me know if I am wrong. My 9-patch works fine though.